# Incidence number $CW$ complex

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I'm studying $CW$ complex from Massey "A basic course in algebraic topology" and I don't understand the following senteces in order to prove Lemma 5.2 (page 241).

The setup is the following, we have

$$ H_n(\overline{e}_{\lambda}^n,\partial \overline{e}_{\lambda}^n )\overset{l_{\lambda*}}{\longrightarrow} H_n(K^n,K^{n-1})\overset{m_{\lambda*}}{\longrightarrow} H_n(K^n, K^n-e_{\lambda}^n)$$

With $$m_{\lambda*} \circ l_{\lambda*} = l'_{\lambda*} : H_n(\overline{e}_{\lambda}^n,\partial \overline{e}_{\lambda}^n ) \longrightarrow H_n(K^n, K^n-e_{\lambda}^n)$$

Here  $l'_{\lambda*}$ and $m_{\lambda*}$ are induced by incluson which is why the diargram commute.

In order to prove Lemma 5.2 the book says "To prove the assertion about $m_{\lambda *}$, one must prove that if $e_{\lambda}^n \ne e_{\mu}^n$ then $m_{\mu*} \circ l_{\lambda*} =0$; this is an easy consequence on Lemma 5.3 below".

The cited lemma is the following :

***Lemma 5.3*** *: Let $f: (X,A) \longrightarrow (Y,B)$ be a map of pair which is homotopic to a map $g : (X,A) \longrightarrow (Y,B)$ sucht that $g(X) \subset B$. Then the induced homomorphism
$$f_* : H_n(X,A) \longrightarrow H_n(Y,B)$$
is zero for all $n$.*

I do understand the proof of *Lemma 5.3* but I don't see how I should use in this case with $m_{\mu*} \circ l_{\lambda*}$, if this is $f$, who's $g$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f = m_{\mu} \circ l_{\lambda} : (\overline{e}_{\lambda}^n,\partial \overline{e}_{\lambda}^n )\overset{l_{\lambda}}{\longrightarrow} (K^n,K^{n-1})\overset{m_{\mu}}{\longrightarrow} (K^n, K^n \setminus e_{\mu}^n)$. Clearly $f(\overline{e}_{\lambda}^n) \cap e_{\mu}^n = \emptyset$, i.e. Lemma 5.3 applies (with $g = f$).

Comment: So in this case $B = K^n \backslash e_{\mu}^n$ ? The thing that doesn't feel intuitive to me is that in order to prove that the composition is the null homomorphism is sufficient to prove that $\text{Imm} l_{\lambda*} \subseteq \text{Ker} m_{\mu *}$ but doens't seem what I'm doing.

Comment: @jacopoburelli Yes, $(Y,B)  = (K^n, K^n \setminus e_{\mu}^n)$. What may seem not intuitive is that although both $l_{\lambda^*}$ and $m_{\mu^*}$ are non-zero, their composition is zero. But if you consider about it on the level of $m_{\mu} \circ l_{\lambda}$, it becomes clear.